# C# - Convert String with Public Key (mod) and Exponent RSA PKCS#1.5

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I have a publickey that is:

> a383a2916281721498ff28226f851613bab6f89eb0536e9f237e158596d3b012e5707eba9f2a2963faca63fcb10f5de79caf246c1f587ee6e8f895fd848f2da5aba9d71af4dd8d06e99ff3729631626ed3f3202e56962957c0110a99d2b3893feb148291e09b54fe7df121751fb8bb589576542321b4f548be06b9845ebc6bbef1427741c00b632c05854146b597fdef5a89ace1556a769c5eaff8fc0589e7ad4adb2e2a929969c77f395b2f5a276a9389d1f43c061c9459a65b77bcd581c107aa8424223a0b44ee52582362cc96b90eea071a0dda5e9cb8fd5c9fd4ac86e177c07d79071788cb08231240dc1c9169af2629ecec31751069f0c7ccc1c1752303
>   (Not Base64)

and an exponent thats:

> 010001
>   (Again not base64)

and I need to convert this along with a small string to RSA PKCS#1.5
But im a bit confused, it keeps giving me errors when trying to do it
apparently the exponent is formatted wrong and the public key isnt base64?

Heres my code

```
string publicKey = "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";
string exponant = "010001";
string toEncrypt = "Test123";
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    RSAParameters rsap = new RSAParameters {
        Modulus = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publicKey))),
        Exponent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exponant)))
    };
    //Tried with and without the whole base64 thing
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsap);
    byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt), false);
    string base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    x = x.Replace(match, text.Contains("(URLENCODE)") ? WebUtility.UrlEncode(base64Encrypted) : base64Encrypted);
}
```

CryptographicException: Bad Data.
Occuring On: rsa.ImportParameters(rsap);

I do have the finished result:

> PV7v6F8AOJvIJA6yYJReUf3jRD8HL5LzNIIqs4ehKlwxt00xyvnCCy/MiSX/4ZP6+IZfXPGAs57kM2/KsUau+fgU4p0rxJM569MLZ+RFjBnI/ATE1Ru5v8D2ZcJ89Y0Z3xowVnNMaytwacRf/LZqxIAFpBr/E5G6KSHkSg+3zQIu6RrxbHPrWeiYYUWB5XfYDKlPcezW3QYi9lktGCp2Eqsg+ULX1GD6qIlHySslYlT3kqVZbQb1B5ak416Rq1RMLhUgpsBazuB50jr5I1zfrFdi4UeNlkBWxFcJaGOY8HScCKwvlGU7TqGbjucB1rA3mQhGvSTUmfDeGBnGrLwCdA==
>   (Got this from using the same data in a non c# non open-source application).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the errors you are facing.

Comment: I guess the error you are facing is related to `testData` size, right? Test the encryption with a smaller plain text string.

Comment: @Dalton Edited, and I slightly updated the code, the code was accidentally trying to encrypt the Public Key (Wasnt occuring on my end, was just from editing mistake when making question). And the testData string is like 7 characters long

Comment: Is it possible I need to "Pad" it to the 1.5 standards and manually ConvertToBase64()?

Comment: If I convert the modulus to byte array and then to base64 string from that byte array, it gives me the error: FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Comment: Try converting both `publicKey` and `exponent` to base64 format

Comment: Here you can see an example, in which the public key is in base64 format (see the = symbol at the end): https://gist.github.com/zachbonham/3692542

Comment: @Dalton Tried that, and I updated the code to something a bit cleaner with a new error.

Comment: Another attempt: try to encrypt with just the public key in base64 format (not the exponent).

Comment: @Dalton Same error occurs "Bad data."

Comment: Why are you encoding again to UTF (`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`) after passing to base64?

Comment: @Dalton Its asking for Moodulus and Exponent to be as byte[] array

Comment: See this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67b50472-b23f-4191-b8f4-e4a696fca5e4/how-to-use-a-public-key-with-rsacryptoserviceprovider-class?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The public key string you have looks like the hexadecimal representation of a byte array to me. Therefore, I tested to convert it to a `byte[]` using the following conversion:

```
public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(hexString.Length / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
    {
        stream.WriteByte(byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
    }
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Also, the exponent probably has the same format (3 bytes, 0x01 0x00 0x01), therefore I am using the same approach to convert it to a `byte[]`

At the end, the code looks like:

```
string publicKey = "a383a2916281721498ff28226f851613bab6f89eb0536e9f237e158596d3b012e5707eba9f2a2963faca63fcb10f5de79caf246c1f587ee6e8f895fd848f2da5aba9d71af4dd8d06e99ff3729631626ed3f3202e56962957c0110a99d2b3893feb148291e09b54fe7df121751fb8bb589576542321b4f548be06b9845ebc6bbef1427741c00b632c05854146b597fdef5a89ace1556a769c5eaff8fc0589e7ad4adb2e2a929969c77f395b2f5a276a9389d1f43c061c9459a65b77bcd581c107aa8424223a0b44ee52582362cc96b90eea071a0dda5e9cb8fd5c9fd4ac86e177c07d79071788cb08231240dc1c9169af2629ecec31751069f0c7ccc1c1752303";
            string exponant = "010001";
            string toEncrypt = "Test123";
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSAParameters rsap = new RSAParameters
                {
                    Modulus = HexStringToByteArray(publicKey),
                    Exponent = HexStringToByteArray(exponant)
                };
                //Tried with and without the whole base64 thing
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsap);
                byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt), false);
                string base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
```

The import of the RSA parameters is successful, and the encryption too.

The output looks like the following. It does not have to be the same as yours (which you produced by using a non C#, non open source application, by the way with which I sensed some kind of reproach) because there are other factors like padding which affects the result, but the encryption is successful.

```
VXg8wRZz7SDnhg3T1GPs8CztjPsGwES+ngJAaBBVMSNkBiBOU+ju70pI5sAjvFS34+ztY8VLUZZ4vzf9
NkBNCgEn7Q2NezOwgP029yHY169Jc7Kqkwy0UbJLAwCwmqR+/G6B/S2hL2ADV+5EeaEn4ZmmKl/WRp+P
ruwWKDQx46/ih0itvh7uF5/OfKCqeIrcsqpZgQ4pByNQNOTs1sFlKB+/8TZ6Ey00lYU8c3bRLOef0Nh+
uivY0LI2ryOYI//EtmoZqfkeJH2ZqOQPy/I4R/OXHs1RcEZpnam8/OF1c/DlGVp3//RO8owmStxSj/eF
TD5arc3a1kiNma+/DDQYuQ==
```